# Dijkstras algorithm on tree graph

Tags: dijkstra

I have been searching some information about Dijsktras algorithm, and I found that its alway beeing applied to this kind of graph. Is it possible to use Dijkstra if I have tree/heap structure of graph ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dijsktras's algorithm is a  single-source shortest path algorithm for general graphs with weighted edges. As long as your data structure **is** a graph with quantifiable edge weights (can be all 1), there should be no reason why it does not work.